# FlutterFire configure CLI requires the official Firebase CLI

Tags: flutter, command-line-interface

I'm having a problem to configure Flutter Fire to my project. I installed using npm install -g firebase-tools --force and then I tried > dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli but i still have a problem with CLI. I can login and see the version but i can't run flutterfire configure

```
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version 
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
```

After read all the topics on stackoverflow and on internet i can't solve my problem, any ideas?
Running  npm install -g firebase-tools I got this:

```
>  npm install -g firebase-tools
C:\Users\loveh\.cache\firebase\tools\firebase -> C:\Users\loveh\.cache\firebase\tools\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
+ firebase-tools@11.0.1
updated 1 package in 11.091s
```

Now it's appearing this error:

```
⠋ Fetching available Firebase projects...
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:264:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:351:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     main (file:///C:/Users/loveh/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutterfire_cli-0.2.2+2/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

News

```
 npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/d
ebug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 691 packages, and audited 692 packages in 36s

38 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

25 vulnerabilities (15 moderate, 10 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: Are you able to run this without `--force` `npm install -g firebase-tools --force` ? There should be an error log generated, please share that. I assume you already tried `firebase logout` and `firebase login`?

Comment: I will edit the post with the error log. Yes i've tried logout and login :c

Comment: No error log generated

Comment: What does `firebase --version` give you?

Comment: it gives me 11.0.1

Comment: Ive tried uninstalling node and installing again, and reinstalling firebase but it not worked

Comment: Strange, not sure I can help. Try `firebase login --reauth`. There is not `firebase-debug.log`?

Comment: +  Success! Logged in as ****************

> flutterfire configure
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version 
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

Comment: Could you / did you run `firebase init` in the project folder? If so, please run `flutterfire configure` and check if a log appears.

Comment: it give me some options, what should i choose?
Storage: Configure a security rules file for Cloud Storage
 ( ) Emulators: Set up local emulators for Firebase products
 ( ) Remote Config: Configure a template file for Remote Config
>( ) Realtime Database: Configure a security rules file for Realtime Database and (optionally) provision default instance
 ( ) Firestore: Configure security rules and indexes files for Firestore
 (*) Functions: Configure a Cloud Functions directory and its files
 ( ) Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys

Comment: You can always change these later on by invoking the same command. For now, go with `Hosting` but without github. The defaults are pretty ok.

Comment: there's only 2 hosting, Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys
>(*) Hosting: Set up GitHub Action deploys

Comment: The first one with `(optionally)`.

Comment: Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? public
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
+  Wrote public/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

+  Firebase initialization complete!

Comment: Well, try running `flutterfire config`.

Comment: then i tried to use flutterfire configure and it not worked

Comment: Does it show the same error? Is there a `firebase-debug.log` or any other log?

Comment: i forgot to send this part 
> flutterfire configure
i Found 0 Firebase projects.
its like i dont have projects but i have

Comment: no logs my friend :c i'm so upset about this. or i'm looking into the wrong place? where i can find your log?

Comment: yes, the same error appears

Comment: I guess you checked that you logged in locally with the same user-email you use when visiting https://console.firebase.google.com (top-right part of the screen) ?

Comment: yes with the same user email

Comment: I edited the document with the new issue

Comment: Odd, try `firebase login --reauth` again?

Comment: New problem: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\firepit\welcome.js:115:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)

Comment: I suggest creating a new flutter project. In your shell, go to a directory and call `flutter create my_test`. The go into `cd my_test` and  call `flutterfire configure` from there.

Comment: Also, `snapshot\firepit\welcome.js` means that in the folder `snapshot` is an old installation of yours that you probably do not want, as you have everything installed via `npm`. In case `c:\snapshot` is still in your path, remove it from your path and restart your shell. Renaming snapshot to snapshotX will also do. The to again login an logout.

Comment: there's no snapshot in my c:\ but i reinstalled firebase tools and i have some news. i will edit the post

Comment: If i try flutterfire configure inside my project it doesnt works but if i try inside .\firebase (that i renamed firebase-tools-instant-win.exe to firebase.exe) it  gives me that The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli

Comment: It looks like you have installed two instances of firebase: One with the windows installer and one with NPM. I guess, these two conflict with each other. If using NPM, remove the firebase.exe.

Comment: Good for you! I suggest always using NPM. It is much more convenient, although it may seem more complicated at first.

Comment: Yeah i'm kinda new to flutter, i just know basic things. But i'm trying to learn more and more every day. Thank you for the help and tips. You're the best

Answer (score 3):

Remove the previously installed `firebase.exe` and rely on `firebase` installed via `npm install -g firebase-tools` only.

The problem resulted from conflicting installations.

Comment: this is the path for windows users C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\ delete firebase files -> update node js -> reinstall firebase tools by the above command, and start flutter fire cli again :)

Answer (score 2):

If you get the `FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)` error, look if you have a **firebase.exe** file in your flutter main folder. This was my problem. After deleting the file, `flutterfire configure` works with no problem.

Clarification:
I have added the firebase-cli binary (firebase-tools-instant-win.exe) to the main folder of my flutter project and renamed it to firebase.exe because of previuos bug fix attempts. If you don't have done that, there should be no firebase binary in your flutter main folder.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved for me by doing the following after struggling with plenty of errors

1. Use nvm to install latest node
2. Change the default directory for packages on windows pc using prefix command. For me I created directory here %appdata%.npm-global and go to this directory then use prefix command to set the default for npm global packages
3. Ensure this path is in your windows PATH
4. Install firebase tools npm install -g firebase-tools
5. Install flutterfire cli dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
6. cd to my flutter app directory
7. From command prompt firebase login
8. type flutterfire configure

Ensure you do not have the windows exe downloaded as it may conflict when you run firebase/flutterfire.  For me, the trick was to ensure I used nvm to install npm, setting default directory install for npm global to something other than default.  I believe this was a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 2023 for Windows 11**

1. Download stand-alone binary [Firebase CLI executable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows) (`firebase-tool-instant-win.exe`) to "Downloads" folder
2. Run the executable from Downloads. Do not move it or rename it, this makes it unhappy for some reason. Perhaps it does not want to be moved after the first run. Not sure. If you really want to move it do it before you run it I guess, at your own risk!

You should see an output like below:

[image: firebase login screen]

3. In Firebase CLI use `cd` (change directory) commands to get to your flutter project folder, same as you would have done in Windows cmd.
4. Still in Firebase CLI run the following command:
   `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`
5. If the output says that `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` is not on your path, you will have to add this to the path, then restart your pc. To add this to your path, search Windows Control Panel for "path"

[image: Windows path]

Don't forget to restart!

6. If you had to restart to add a path, repeat steps from #2
7. Finally run this command (also in Firebase CLI):
   `flutterfire configure`

Answer (score 1):

It's JDK Path Problem you need to add Java JDK do the following seps:

1. Add JDK path to your user variables as example `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin`.
2. then restart your terminal and try again `flutterfire configur` command.
   it work with me.

Answer (score 0):

just update your platform to latest version [windows or linux or mac] it worked for me , hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

For me it is solved by running command in cmd itself not in internal terminal of Android Studio.

[image: Running Command in Android Studio but not working]

but

[image: the same command in cmd itself is working and done]

Answer (score 0):

If you installed firebase-tools while your IDE was open, then you'd get that error if you run `flutterfire configure` afterwards. My guess is that environment variables got changed.

Solutions (any would work):

1. Just restart the IDE. Worked for me.
2. Open a new cmd window, navigate to your projects root directory and run the `flutterfire configure` command again